# iOS UITableView appears twice

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have two UITableViewControllers, say, first one is Patient, second one is Medicine. Clicking on one TableViewCell of first UITableView (Patient) will lead to second UITableView that shows this selected patient's medicines. I have my Show Segue defined on Storyboard.

Let me describe what the problem is I sometime faces. I click on one patient, it does not move to Medicine screen right away. The navigation does not kick off right away. After some time, for example, half a second, I click on the patient again, then suddenly two Medicine UITableViewControllers move left, with first one quickly being covered by the second one. I am sure that both Medicine UITableViewControllers live on the Navagation Controller stack, because I can click Back button on upper left corner and still go to the first Medicine screen.

This problem happens very rarely, usually upon opening the app for the first time after installation. I have seen this on both simulators and real devices. For your information, I check location permission on second screen, the Medicine screen, and ask for it if it was not granted.

So, what is the problem? How can I fix it? Any resource related to this? Please help.

---

Storyboard
[image]

---

Code (PatientTVController.swift)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {        
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender) // call parent

    guard segue.source is PatientTVController else {
        fatalError("Unexpected source: \(segue.source)")
    }
    guard let serviceTableViewController = segue.destination as? ServiceTVController else {
        fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
    }
    guard let selectedPatientCell = sender as? PatientTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(String(describing: sender))")
    }
    guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: selectedPatientCell) else {
        fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed")
    }
    let selectedPatient = patients[indexPath.row]

    // set patient id here, 

}
```

Comment: you need to show some code from both the vcs and storyboard connections

Comment: We can't tell for sure what's going on without seeing code, but that sort of delayed response is often caused by trying to update the UI from a background thread. Are you triggering your table view updates in response to a network GET, or async database request? Some of those completion handlers/delegate methods get called on a background thread by default.

Comment: As both of the previous comments said, you need to share a piece of code, another probable cause of that is that you're triggering your segue from both code and on the tap action on the cell linked on the storyboard, this is assuming that you have your views in storyboard of course

Comment: What code would I need? Prepare(for: segue)?

Answer (score 0):

Without many details, it is hard to specifically tell where the error is. If you could show some code to clearly see what is causing the error that would help a lot. However, you can try out this approach.

Try removing your current segue and set a new segue from the PatientTVController instead of the cell of the UItableView, like shown in the picture. Hold down the "control" key and click and drag from the view controller to create a new segue.

[image: New segue]
[image: Selected segue]

Select the segue and navigate to the attribute inspector and add an identifier to the segue.

[image: Segue identifier]

Using the method didSelectRowAt, perform the segue programmatically

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // You can catch the selected patient here and use it later when you need it.

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
}
```